# Do I need a nested query or is there a way to just multiply?

Tags: sql

I am trying to run a query to ultimately have a column that multiplies my count_product_code (count of how many of each product by a specific SKU are sold) and my purchase_size (how many of what item were purchased on each transaction) to get a total_product_sold. Initially when I attempted to do this it did not recognize the count_product_code in the query as a separate name figure 1

So I tried to do a nested query and came out to this result figure 2. What am I doing wrong? Is a nested query even necessary for this?
Database: project-1-349215.customer_data.customer_purchases

Figure 1

`select count(product_code) as count_product_code,  safe_multiply(purchase_size, count_product_code) as total_products_sold, product_code,  initcap(product) as product_name,  initcap(product_color) as product_color, purchase_size, from` project-1-349215.customer_data.customer_purchases `where product is not null group by 2,3,4,5 order by count_product_code desc`

Figure 2

```
select safe_multiply(purchase_size, count_product_code) as total_products_sold,
```

product_code,
initcap(product) as product_name,
initcap(product_color),
purchase_size

(
SELECT count(product_code)
from `project-1-349215.customer_data.customer_purchases`
group by product_code
) as count_product_code

from `project-1-349215.customer_data.customer_purchases`
where product is not null
group by 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Tag your database, provide sample data, provide code as text (not picture).

Comment: Hi Cetin, I believe I input what you asked. Sorry, I am still new to this platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give the details and sample data :( I could guess this is google bigquery but not sure. If it is bigquery then this should run and do what you need:

```
with counts as (select count(product_code)    as count_product_code,
                       product_code,
                       initcap(product)       as product_name,
                       initcap(product_color) as product_color,
                       purchase_size
                from project-1-349215.customer_data.customer_purchases
                where product is not null
                group by 2, 3, 4, 5)
select count_product_code,
       safe_multiply(purchase_size, count_product_code) as total_products_sold,
       product_code,
       product_name,
       product_color,
       purchase_size
from counts
order by count_product_code desc;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. But may I ask, is there a good resource that you would recommend for understanding subqueries better? I cannot seem to grasp the syntax. Again, thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @van_diesel1, I don't know a particular resource. w3schools have basic information, database specific documentation have good information in general. For this specific case, you can think of it as 2 separate SQL, first one placing the result in a virtual table called counts and the second one is using that counts table as the source.